# How to use custom font in fast report for delphi

Tags: delphi, fonts, fastreport

i am using fast report with delphi and i am using fontAwesome icons in my report , in my design page every thing is OK, but when i print the report on page or export it to PDF , there are '?' instead of fontAwesome icons.

Comment: What version of Delphi? What version of Fast Reports? Earlier versions of Delphi did not enforce Unicode, and thus showed a `?` for such characters.

Comment: See here: https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=7187